# Why is my riot.js tag not rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, riot.js

I have the following content:

~/scripts/riot_templates/bob.tag:

```
<bob>

    <h3>{title}</h3>
    <p>{body}</p>

</bob>
```

~/scripts/riot_templates/bob.js

```
riot.tag2('bob', '<h3>{title}</h3> <p>{body}</p>', '', '', function(opts) {
});
```

~/some_file.cshtml::includes (yes it's ASP.NET MVC, that should be ok surely?):

```
<script lang="text/javascript" src="~/lib/riot/riot.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/riot_templates/bob.js"></script>            
<script>riot.mount('bob', { title: "hi", body: "body" })</script>
```

some_file.cshtml::content

```
<p>somenormal html</p>
<bob></bob>
```

and i just cannot get my "bob" tag to render how i want. i'm stuck. and i know it's dumb. i just know it.

Answer (score 1):

When passing data to your tag, you access them via the "opts" object. In your  tag, you should therefore access the variables via :

```
<h3>{opts.title}</h3>
<p>{opts.body}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To go on from ojorma answer, in the case of a web site running on IIS add the tag extension to the mime types for global use alternatively to configure this on an app by app basis (or whilst debugging in IIS Express) add the following to the web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".tag" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".tag" mimeType="text/plain" />
</staticContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

the .tag extension has to be added to the mimetypes in asp.net for it to work